# Cosmwasm environment setup error: "first path segment in URL cannot contain colon"

Tags: go, rust, cosmos-sdk

I'm trying to go through the [Cosmwasm docs](https://docs.cosmwasm.com/docs/1.0/getting-started/setting-env/) and I'm stuck on the "Setting Up Environment" step.

I'm on Ubuntu so when I put the parameters under #bash in my .bashrc script along with saving "tcp://0.0.0.0:26657" to the $RPC environment variable, and "cliffnet-1" for the $CHAIN_ID environment variable, then restart terminal, and then try `wasmd query bank total $NODE`.

I get the following error below.

```
Error: couldn't get client from nodeURI: parse "--node tcp://0.0.0.0:26657": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
Usage:
  wasmd query bank total [flags]

Flags:
      --denom string    The specific balance denomination to query for
      --height int      Use a specific height to query state at (this can error if the node is pruning state)
  -h, --help            help for total
      --node string     <host>:<port> to Tendermint RPC interface for this chain (default "tcp://localhost:26657")
  -o, --output string   Output format (text|json) (default "text")

Global Flags:
      --chain-id string     The network chain ID
      --home string         directory for config and data (default "/home/j/.wasmd")
      --log_format string   The logging format (json|plain) (default "plain")
      --log_level string    The logging level (trace|debug|info|warn|error|fatal|panic) (default "info")
      --trace               print out full stack trace on errors
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not fully up to date. Try with testnet `https://rpc.malaga-420.cosmwasm.com:443`:

```bash
# store node address
wasmd config node 'https://rpc.malaga-420.cosmwasm.com:443'
wasmd status

# or to use in a shell
export NODE='https://rpc.malaga-420.cosmwasm.com:443'
wasmd status

#  or to use for a single query/ command
wasmd status --node='https://rpc.malaga-420.cosmwasm.com:443'
```

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/InterWasm/docs/issues/417) to get the docs updated.